# How to calculate this integral associated with Gamma function?

Tags: integration, derivatives

The integral has the form,
$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{(-bx^2)}dx$$

Comment: Really trivial question: set $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}z$, then $z=\sqrt{t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $bx^2=u$ or $x=\sqrt{\frac ub}$.

$$\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-bx^2}\ dx=\frac1{2b^{1.5}}\int_0^\infty u^{0.5}e^{-u}\ du$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Evaluate $I(b)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-bx^2}~dx,~$ and then notice that your integral can be written as $-I'(b).$